# Ruby, how to overwrite the setter ("=") method to allow 2 parameters?

Tags: ruby, overwrite

I am trying to create a quick *set* method for my multi component variable (in my real code it is a Vector2d).

I would like to use an overwritten version of the `=` method.

For example:

```
def my_vector=(x, y)
  @my_vector = Vector2d.new(x, y)
end
```

But it is not working because when I try to call this method I receive an error:

```
my_vector=1, 2 # => wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
my_vector=(1, 2) # => syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
my_vector=[1, 2] # => wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
```

This is my test suite:

```
# With one param it works
def my_var=(value)
  @var = value
end

self.my_var=1
puts "var: " + @var.to_s


# With 2 params it doesn't work
def my_other_var=(value1, value2)
  @other_var_component_1 = value1
  @other_var_component_2 = value2
end

# Nothing works:
# self.my_other_var=1, 2
# self.my_other_var=(1, 2)
# self.my_other_var=[1, 2]
puts "other_var_component_1: " + @other_var_component_1.to_s
puts "other_var_component_2: " + @other_var_component_2.to_s
```

Comment: Assignment is **designed** to have only one argument on the rhs. Even you you write `x=4,5,6`, this simply passes the one argument [4,5,6] to x. Why do you want to change it? You wouldn't want to define a binary operator (such as `/` or `|`) to accept more than two arguments either, wouldn't you? How is Ruby supposed to parse it?

Comment: I was expecting ruby to parse this as in any other method call, so accept as many parameters as I have defined in my overwritten version, I think my use case is a clear example. And yes, to accept more of than one parameter in any operator if I have deliberately overwritten it this way.

Comment: I am not aware of *any* programming language which supports binary operators in infix notation, and would allow them to overload it to more than one argument. Note also that parsing is done before by the compiler (to generate the intermediate code), while method-lookup is done at runtime. The parser can't know for any method, how many parameters it expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @eugen correctly says, you cannot pass two arguments to a setter like

```rb
self.my_vector = 1, 2
```

The nearest thing you can achieve is to unpack the argument using pattern matching:

```rb
def myvector=(arg)
  arg => [x, y]
  @my_vector = Vector2d.new(x, y)
end

foo.my_vector = [1, 2]
```

An alternative is to define a simple helper method `v` so you can write

```rb
foo.my_vector = v 1, 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You're defining a method named `my_vector=` (or `my_other_var=` in your 2nd example).

If you're just trying to call it with

```
my_vector = 1, 2
```

ruby will interpret that as an assignment to the `my_vector` variable.

You'll have to use `send` in order to call the method you've defined, as in

```
self.send :my_vector=, 1, 2
```

That's kind of ugly, but I don't see another way around this.

Comment: Thanks, I was hopping to find a more elegant solution :/

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification to the supplied code to use an array argument instead:

```
 def my_other_var=(values)
   @other_var_component_1 = values[0]
   @other_var_component_2 = values[1]
 end
    
 self.my_other_var=[1, 2]
    
"other_var_component_1: " + @other_var_component_1.to_s
#=>  other_var_component_1: 1
"other_var_component_2: " + @other_var_component_2.to_s
#=>  other_var_component_2: 2
```

Comment: Ten minutes late, but I give you a vote up ;)

Comment: @fguillen: Ah, yes.  I missed that.  I saw it, but it seemed to be solving a different use case.  I was also focused in on your last/test example and kinda forgot about the first example.